# Is is possible to estimate a mixed logit model with only individual specific parameters?

Tags: modeling, econometrics, random-effects-model, discrete-data

I am analyzing some data and I do not have any alternative specific variables in the dataset. The question is about the preference between taxi, uber and automated vehicle if all three have the same price and waiting time. The four choices are 1, 2, 3 and no preference. The only covariates that I have are demographics such as age, gender, household income and education level. Using this data, I have to test for heterogeneity in responses and work with random parameter. Is it possible and if so what package can be used for this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is alternative specific variable? Why do you need random parameter in the model, or, which condition(s) for fixed effect logit model is violated in you data?

Comment: @Ak05, `mlogit` is `Stata` as an example.